# Request to delete an accepted answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer, vote-to-delete

The answer in question (written by me):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490811/532430

I have flagged the answer in the past and seemingly nobody is able to do anything about it.

Please accept the highest voted answer and delete this one.

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention and explain that you want your answer deleted. In case of a negatively-voted answer the moderators will likely follow your request and delete your answer

Comment: I have flagged it again. But I already had in the past, mutiple times. Nobody seems to be able/willing to do anything, the answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: You could also make it community wiki or ask to have it disassociated from your account, if deleting doesn't work out.

Comment: If you so desperately want it gone, I've casted the first delete vote. Seems to need 2 more to get this done and over with.

Comment: voted to delete

Comment: Answer is deleted now.

Comment: "Accept the highest voted answer" won't work. Accepting is an OP's exclusive privilege. You could ping them but they have not been seen for 4 years...